# element is "not defined" while implementing loop scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops, infinite-scroll

beginner here.
trying to implement a looping scroll on my menu from this codepen: https://codepen.io/vincentorback/pen/zxRyzj

but I am running into a problem: the "js-loop" element returns "not defined", "null", or "undefined" depending where I am trying to place it in my code. I have read the MDN page about this but can't find the exact reason. I think it's just a matter of loading time.  Can someone help me out ? thanks in advance :)

```js
var myContext;
var clones;
var disableScroll = false;
var scrollHeight = 0;
var scrollPos = 0;
var clonesHeight = 0;
var i = 0;

function starting() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var item0 = document.getElementById("item-0")
    item0.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
    console.log("started")
  }, 400);
};






function getScrollPos() {
  return (myContext.pageYOffset || context.scrollTop) - (context.clientTop || 0);
}

function setScrollPos(pos) {
  myContext.scrollTop = pos;
}

function getClonesHeight() {
  clonesHeight = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < clones.length; i += 1) {
    clonesHeight = clonesHeight + clones[i].offsetHeight;
  }

  return clonesHeight;
}

function reCalc() {
  scrollPos = getScrollPos();
  scrollHeight = myContext.scrollHeight;
  clonesHeight = getClonesHeight();

  if (scrollPos <= 0) {
    setScrollPos(1); // Scroll 1 pixel to allow upwards scrolling
  }
}

function scrollUpdate() {
  if (!disableScroll) {
    scrollPos = getScrollPos();

    if (clonesHeight + scrollPos >= scrollHeight) {
      // Scroll to the top when you’ve reached the bottom
      setScrollPos(1); // Scroll down 1 pixel to allow upwards scrolling
      disableScroll = true;
    } else if (scrollPos <= 0) {
      // Scroll to the bottom when you reach the top
      setScrollPos(scrollHeight - clonesHeight);
      disableScroll = true;
    }
  }

  if (disableScroll) {
    // Disable scroll-jumping for a short time to avoid flickering
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      disableScroll = false;
    }, 40);
  }
}

function init() {
  console.log("init")
  starting();
  myContext = document.querySelector('.js-loop');
  clones = myContext.querySelectorAll('.is-clone');
  setScrollPos(Math.round(clones[0].getBoundingClientRect().top + getScrollPos() - (context.offsetHeight - clones[0].offsetHeight) / 2));

  reCalc();

  myContext.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollUpdate);
  }, false);

  window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(reCalc);
  }, false);
}

if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {

  //  init()
} else {

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false)

}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div id="menu" class="col-2">
        <div class="js-loop" id="loop">
            <ul>

                <!-- menuitem (unfinished) -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <button>
                            <li class="menuItemNone unfinished"> (coming soon)
                            </li>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- menuitem list-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <button>
                            <li class="menuItem" id=item-0> Designing Design<br> and <br>Design Designs

                            </li>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <button>
                            <li class="menuItem" id=item-1> Everyday <br>Design <br> and <br> Designed
                                <br>Everyday

                            </li>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <button>
                            <li class="menuItem" id=item-2> Speculative <br> Design <br> and <br> Speculating
                                <br> Design <br> <span class="italic">(an interview with <br>Dunne & Raby)
                                </span>

                            </li>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <button>
                            <li class="menuItem">Poetic<br> Design <br> and <br> Designing <br> Poetry

                            </li>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <button>
                            <li class="menuItem">Design in <br> the World <br> and<br> Design about <br> the
                                World

                            </li>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <button>
                            <li class="menuItem">Design <br>Epistemology <br> and <br> Epistemological <br>
                                Design

                            </li>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <button>
                            <li class="menuItem"> Design is <br> Fucked<br> and <br> Fuck <br>Design <br> <span
                                    class="italic">(by
                                    Nova Olson)</span>

                            </li>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <button>
                            <li class="menuItem"> Fixation on <br> Design<br> and <br> Design's <br> Fixedness
                                <br> <span class="italic">(an open letter to Alice Rawsthorn)</span>

                            </li>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <button>
                            <li class="menuItem unfinished">Who <br>Designs<br>and<br>Whose <br>Design
                            </li>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <button>
                            <li class="menuItem unfinished"> Curating <br> Design<br> and <br> Design as <br>
                                Curation <br> <span class="italic">(by Zeniya Vreugdenhil)</span>
                            </li>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <button o> Design <br> Education <br> and <br> Designing <br>
                            Education <br>
                            <span class="italic">(by Samein Shamsher)</span>
                            </li>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <button>
                            <li class="menuItem unfinished"> Failed Design <br> and <br> the Failing <br> of
                                Design <br> <span class="italic">(by Lara Chapman)</span>
                            </li>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <button>
                            <li class="menuItem unfinished"> (coming soon)
                            </li>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- clones loop -->
                <div class="row is-clone">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <button>
                            <li class="menuItem" id=item-0> Designing Design<br> and <br>Design Designs

                            </li>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row is-clone">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <button>
                            <li class="menuItem" id=item-1> Everyday <br>Design <br> and <br> Designed
                                <br>Everyday

                            </li>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row is-clone">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <button>
                            <li class="menuItem" id=item-2> Speculative <br> Design <br> and <br> Speculating
                                <br> Design <br> <span class="italic">(an interview with <br>Dunne & Raby)
                                </span>

                            </li>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```